# How to stop ReSharper from removing unused Using statements when moving/updating Namespace declarations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, resharper, using-statement

When using ReSharper to move/update namespace declarations, is there a way to stop ReSharper from removing unused Using statements?

In other words, if I have a class such as:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace Foo.Bar
{
    class MyClass
    {
        List<string> Names { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I want to move it into the Foo.Bar.Utilities namespace using ReSharper, Resharper will remove all the unused Using statements and leave me with:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Foo.Bar.Utilities
{
    class MyClass
    {
        List<string> Names { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, I do not want ReSharper to touch my Using statements while moving the namespace declaration. I'd prefer to have the result as:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace Foo.Bar.Utilities
{
    class MyClass
    {
        List<string> Names { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why this does not agree with you?

Comment: If they are unused, why are you finding it to be such a problem?

Comment: Often times I'll bring in my namespaces prior to using them, i.e., for a 3rd party assembly. I may not have used the 3rd party assembly, but will in short order; during a quick refactor to a different namespace, ReSharper will remove my using statement. Additionally, my preference is to not remove the using statements until the end of the end of the development; at which time I'll remove the unused statements and any associated assembly references.

Comment: Don't Using statements get automatically added in when you need them?

Comment: @davr - you have to add them yourself, but if the assembly is referenced VS (and I assume ReSharper) will work out which ones it needs to add.

Comment: F12 and an ALT-F5 will add missing usings for you if you add code later that needs it.  So not sure what the problem really is...

Comment: @Sumo I agree. My view point is more of an OCD thing. Why doesn't class name refactoring remove unused usings, too? It's a matter of isolated functionality and consistency. Touch what you've been given permission to touch is likely a good UX principle.

Comment: @Oded I got the same problem as the OP. I need to use a library of extension methods. I do not necessary use them, but I want to see them in the intellisense to see if there is anything I can use. "Using" them makes the IDE recognize the extension methods. However, ReSharper keeps removing these "usings", which is very annoying in my case.

Comment: Old thread I know but I have a case where I don't want System.Linq removed because I'm cross-compiling the code to compact framework but developing on the full framework. The compact doesn't bundle in System.Linq by default.

Comment: If you use compiler directives resharper thinks that code part is unused so it removes the using statements. That's a big problem! and that's why one may want to prevent this feature.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you can do this unequivocally.

However, there is an option to specify namespaces that should not be removed (Resharper Options -> C# -> Namespace Imports), but you need to know which ones you don't want it to remove.